# Como agregar Data Labels a gráficos en Office Script?

Tags: typescript, excel, macros, office365, power-automate

Llevo ya un par de horas intentando agregar los data labels a un gráfico de excel online mediante un script, este mismo script lo pienso utilizar en un flujo para optimizar los reportes en la empresa que trabajo. Para ello eh estado intentando utilizar la función de record actions sin embargo parece no funcionar cuando lo ejecuto en el flow parece no funcionar. He intentado usar chart.getDataLabels().setPosition(ExcelScript.ChartDataLabelPosition.outsideEnd); inclusive e intentado usar  chart_1.getDataLabels().setShowValue(true); sin embargo parece que ninguno de estos códigos funcionan.

Para darles una idea de lo que busco, les anexo algunas fotos:
[image: Lo que tengo]

[image: Lo que busco]

Bueno eso es lo que busco crear mediante un script en excel. Por ahora mi script es el siguiente:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
// Delete the "TESTING" worksheet if it's present, then recreate it.
workbook.getWorksheet('TESTING')?.delete();
// Add a new worksheet
let probando = workbook.addWorksheet("TESTING");
let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
// Add a new pivot table on probando
let newPivotTable = workbook.addPivotTable("PivotTable1", table1, probando.getRange("A1:C18"));
// Add pivot field to a hierarchy in newPivotTable
newPivotTable.addRowHierarchy(newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Customer Name"));
// Add pivot field to a hierarchy in newPivotTable
newPivotTable.addDataHierarchy(newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Amount due"));

let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("TESTING");
// Insert pivot chart on sheet selectedSheet
let chart_1 = selectedSheet.addChart(ExcelScript.ChartType.pie, newPivotTable.getLayout().getRange());
// Resize and move chart chart_1
chart_1.setLeft(218.25);
chart_1.setTop(0);
chart_1.setWidth(360);
chart_1.setHeight(216);
chart_1.getTitle().setText('Perforacion por Obra');}
```

Y esta vendría a ser mi tabla normal (Table1):
[image: Tabla Excel]

El nombre del worksheet es InvoiceAmounts. Bueno espero que me puedan ayudar, les agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Hola. No queda tan claro lo de los gráficos ¿El primero es el que te elabora el código y el segundo es tal cual te gustaría que quede? Confirma. Saludos

Comment: Que tal abraham, si, el primer gráfico es el que me arroja el código, y el segundo gráfico es el que deseo obtener

Comment: Comenta como estás creando el flujo, quizás ahí radica el problema.

Comment: Por cierto, ejecutado en Excel para la web ¿Si queda como querías?

Comment: Como ejecuto en excel para la web?

Comment: El flujo me funcionaba perfectamente hasta que agregue esas 3 ultimas lineas, solo ejecuta un script en un excel donde esta la tabla 1 y me envia un correo diciéndome que se ejecuto el script (esto lo hace por el momento, luego ya hare que me envíe mas info)

Comment: Excel para la web es el nombre de lo que antes era Excel Online ¿Corriste el Script directamente en el archivo de Excel en la web? ¿Todo bien?

Comment: Lo acabo de ejecutar, sin embargo se intenta ejecutar el script infinitamente, nunca me sale error ni nada pero no termina el script, al igual que cuando ejecuto el flujo, ya que cuando ejecuto el flujo me manda bad gateway y se sigue reintentando infinitamente.

Comment: Me olvide de comentarte, la tabla1 genera una PivotTable, y de esa PivotTable se genera un PivotChart, de repente por eso no funciona, genere el PivotTable para tenerlo agrupado por Customer Name con su suma de Amount Due total, de repente ahi radica el problema

Comment: Mira el cambio que hice en el código propuesto. Al parecer cuando los datos se obtienen de un rango de Tabla Dinámica, para usar los porcentajes hay que hacerlo distinto a cuando el rango del gráfico es de una Tabla de Excel o de un Rango de Datos. Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Abraham, con tu código pude resolver el problema. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de la línea del título del gráfico, agrega las siguientes:

```
chart_1.getSeries()[0].setHasDataLabels(true);
chart_1.getDataLabels().setShowPercentage(true);
chart_1.getDataLabels().setPosition(ExcelScript.ChartDataLabelPosition.outsideEnd);
```

Comentas

Comment: Abraham ahi respondi el error que me salio al ejecutar el nuevo código, no termina de ejecutarse. Nose si tengas otra solución, de igual manera muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo :D

Answer (score 1):

Ejecute el siguiente código:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
// Delete the "TESTING" worksheet if it's present, then recreate it.
workbook.getWorksheet('TESTING')?.delete();
// Add a new worksheet
let probando = workbook.addWorksheet("TESTING");
let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
// Add a new pivot table on probando
let newPivotTable = workbook.addPivotTable("PivotTable1", table1, probando.getRange("A1:C18"));
// Add pivot field to a hierarchy in newPivotTable
newPivotTable.addRowHierarchy(newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Customer Name"));
// Add pivot field to a hierarchy in newPivotTable
newPivotTable.addDataHierarchy(newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Amount due"));

let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("TESTING");
// Insert pivot chart on sheet selectedSheet
let chart_1 = selectedSheet.addChart(ExcelScript.ChartType.pie, newPivotTable.getLayout().getRange());
// Resize and move chart chart_1
chart_1.setLeft(218.25);
chart_1.setTop(0);
chart_1.setWidth(360);
chart_1.setHeight(216);
chart_1.getTitle().setText('Perforacion por Obra');
chart_1.getSeries()[0].setHasDataLabels(true);
chart_1.getSeries()[0].getDataLabels().setShowPercentage(true);
chart_1.getDataLabels().setPosition(ExcelScript.ChartDataLabelPosition.outsideEnd);}
```

Sin embargo, no termino de funcionar en mi flujo, me indica que hay un bad gateway y no se termina de realizar la tarea esperada. No se si tengas otra solución Abraham. De igual manera muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo :D

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias a @Abraham Valencia por resolver mi duda, aquí dejo el código final:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Delete the "TESTING" worksheet if it's present, then recreate it.
  workbook.getWorksheet('TESTING')?.delete();
  // Add a new worksheet
  let probando = workbook.addWorksheet("TESTING");
  let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
  // Add a new pivot table on probando
  let newPivotTable = workbook.addPivotTable("PivotTable1", table1, probando.getRange("A1:C18"));
  // Add pivot field to a hierarchy in newPivotTable
  newPivotTable.addRowHierarchy(newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Customer Name"));
  // Add pivot field to a hierarchy in newPivotTable
  newPivotTable.addDataHierarchy(newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Amount due"));

  let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("TESTING");
  // Insert pivot chart on sheet selectedSheet
  let chart_1 = selectedSheet.addChart(ExcelScript.ChartType.pie, newPivotTable.getLayout().getRange());
  // Resize and move chart chart_1
  chart_1.setLeft(218.25);
  chart_1.setTop(0);
  chart_1.setWidth(360);
  chart_1.setHeight(216);
  chart_1.getTitle().setText('Perforacion por Obra');
  chart_1.getSeries()[0].setHasDataLabels(true);
  chart_1.getDataLabels().setShowPercentage(true);
  chart_1.getDataLabels().setSeparator("\n");
  chart_1.getDataLabels().setPosition(ExcelScript.ChartDataLabelPosition.outsideEnd);
}
```